# What packaging tool should I use for a Mac/Windows Java app?

Tags: java, windows, macos, installation

I have a Java desktop app that runs on both the MacOS and Windows.

I understand that I cannot have one distribution for each, which is not a requirement.

I need to know what tool or tools is best to use when delivering a Java app for each.

The tool should install prerequisites (in this case, Java and some JARs) and look native to the respective operating system.

Comment: You would only ever need to install Java on a Windows box, and not on a Mac.  Apple manages the JRE installation for you, and without going to a fair amount of effort, it is best to just use what they provide.  The JARs that you would need are a different issue though.  Not sure about how to build a Mac installer, but there are a number of Windows tools available.

Comment: "You would only ever need to install Java on a Windows box, and not on a Mac. Apple manages the JRE installation for you". True for now, but I would be careful with the use of *ever* in that sentence. Apple has declared Java support as deprecated, and might stop shipping it with future releases of their OS.

Comment: @Thilo I had not considered that, but you are right.  Hopefully if that happens, Oracle will allow you to download a Mac OS release, because at the moment they don't.  I should revise my statement to say "At the moment, there is no need to install Java on a Mac."

Comment: Oracle will probably do that, and Apple seems to intend to give its code to OpenJDK. But having to depend on the whims of Oracle (to provide a good experience for desktop Java on a minority platform) and of Apple (to not cut it off completely and at least cooperate with JDK engineers), two companies who are known to be brutal against anything outside their core business interests, is a quite a step down from when Mac OS X was first announced, with Java as an equal to Objective-C, and promoted as the best platform to work with Java. :-(

Comment: @{all}, I like the idea of not installing Java for my MacOS installs, I think it is okay to not worry about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for OS X's java situation:

1. Currently, JDK 6 is bundled in the OS.
2. Presumably, the next version of the OS will still include JDK 6.
3. It's publicly stated that the OS will have a well-defined place to install multiple copies of Java runtimes, a public interface choosing which of the Java version, etc. See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Java/JavaSnowLeopardUpdate3LeopardUpdate8RN/NewandNoteworthy/NewandNoteworthy.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010380-CH4-SW1).
4. Apple started contributing back its own code to the open JDK community, so JDK 7 should be available as a separate download, see [here](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/macosx-port/).
5. So, you're not expected to include Java runtime itself into your Java app even then. You're not supposed to install Java in a ramdom place on a filesystem, for example.

As for how you should deploy java apps on OS X:

1. Double-clicking jar just works.
2. However, that won't be pretty, because you would only have a generic Java icon in the Dock. You don't want that.
3. You should use Jar Bundler to make it an honest OS X app. On Mac, it comes with XCode. See the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Conceptual/Jar_Bundler/Introduction/Introduction.html) here. You can do that on a non-Mac machine too, using [this open-source project](http://informagen.com/JarBundler/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, I would recommend either [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/) or [WinRun4J](http://winrun4j.sourceforge.net/).

On a Mac, the situation is a bit more complex (as the comments point out), but just distributing an executable JAR is probably good enough for now.

Comment: Is it normal to simply hand a user a JAR file on a Mac without an installation tool?

Comment: No, a simple JAR is not good enough. It runs, but there is no application icon and other niceties. You do not need to make an installer (Mac apps are installed by copying them to your disk), but you should bundle the JAR in a native wrapper. The basic tool for that is the JarBundler (shipped with the Apple Dev tools).